# sendTextMessage is not applicable

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an app that send gps location with sms,and i got stuck in this error:

The method sendTextMessage(String, String, String, PendingIntent, PendingIntent) in the type SmsManager is not applicable for the arguments (EditText, null, String, null, null)

```
package com.example.thermolocation;import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
           EditText txtphoneNo;
           String Text;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */

    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();


    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);


    }


    /* Class My Location Listener */

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {

    @Override

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

    {

    loc.getLatitude();

    loc.getLongitude();
    Text = "My location is: " +

    "Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() +

    "Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();



    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),Text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    txtphoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
    sendSMSMessage();
    }
    protected void sendSMSMessage() {
        Log.i("Send SMS", "");




        try {
            android.telephony.SmsManager smsManager = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();

        smsManager.sendTextMessage(txtphoneNo, null, Text, null, null);  /* <--here i got the error */
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
           "SMS faild, please try again.",
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }


    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

    {

    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
    "GPS Disabled",


    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    }


    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

    {

    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),


    "GPS Enabled",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

    {


    }

    }
```

Can i get some help please 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite clear:
The method is:
`sendTextMessage(String, String, String, PendingIntent, PendingIntent)` 
but you call it with the arguments `(EditText, null, String, null, null)`

Notice how the first argument is a `EditText` and not a `String` (which it wants)

You should use `txtphoneNo.getText().toString()`

Answer (score 1):

Check your `Error` :

```
The method sendTextMessage(String, String, String, PendingIntent, PendingIntent) in the type SmsManager is not applicable for the arguments (EditText, null, String, null, null)
```

The first argument doesn't match, you are passing an EditText instead of a String.
I suggest you change as following:

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(txtphoneNo.getText().toString(), null, Text, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

EditText is not a string. Change your call to this:

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(txtphoneNo.getText().toString(), null, Text, null, null);
```